# Select menu options not getting selected when we navigate to other pages

Tags: jquery

With the above code I am able to navigate to different pages, But what I need is if I select "page3", that should be in selection mode(I mean it should be selected in dropdown selection menu), which is not happening. Can anybody resolve this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>PAGE1</h1>
        <form>
            <select id="dropdown">
                <option value="index1.html">select</option>
                <option value="index1.html">page1</option>
                <option value="index2.html">page2</option>
                <option value="index3.html">page3</option>
            </select>
        </form> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/customjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$("select").change(function() {  
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't *anyone* format their code anymore?

Comment: do you get any javascript error in the browser console?

Comment: Well, that's how the web works... if you want to preselect a given option in your select box upon page load, you have to write some code for it... which I don't see here

Comment: no I didn't get any errors

Comment: I know I have to write some code....but I want what is that code???

Comment: put in document.ready $(function() { // here your code });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your jQuery code could look like:

This will get the path name of the current URL and select that value in the drop down.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = window.location.pathname; //e.g: "http://www.test.com/index2.html";
    var pagename = url.split("/").pop();

    $("select").val(pagename);

    $("select").change(function() {  
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });

});
```

This solution also assumes that you're not using query strings.